# Dynamic Binding for Settings?

Tags: wpf, xaml, reflection, binding, settings

I am facing a problem, I have a application with several setting's files but which have exactly the same fields.

Sample :

- Profil1.settings
- Profil2.settings
- Profil3.settings

What I'd like to do in my setting window XAML is to dynamicaly change the binding source for each profile.

At the moment my XAML binding look like this :

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:Properties.Profil1.Default}, Path=CurrentProfil, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

My problem is how to replace the "Profil1" by "Profil2" without remaking all my Binding one by one for each controls via my code behind ? Is that possible to use some king of reflection variable in the XAML binding source and than simply change the type of that variable with Profil1 type or Profil2 type ?

Anyone can help me about this ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I've got some clues, by using the type "dynamic" I can assign different Profil type to a dynamic variable and can retrieve setting from it. This is working in code, but I don't know how to make it work with XAML binding. If I try to bind a dynamic type variable in my binding source the compiler throw me error while building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is set the DataContext of your settings window to the appropriate profile.  You can do it anyway you want, but by doing so, all your bindings would point to that object.  To make the bindings work like you have now, you'd do:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:Properties.Profil1.Default}}">

    ...

    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentProfil, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

Comment: I am not at work until monday but yes it look like the solution. All I will have to do is change the DataContext of my window by code to the right profile and it's done. It's a lot easier than working with dynamic type object and binding. Thank you.